# there exists vector space $V$ and linear operator $T$ such that $V$ has exactly three invariant subspaces under T?

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

First of all, i thought there exists searching for some case with an example, but i don't find. Someone has seen the solution of this problem before?
Sorry about my english...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint 1*

> Take $V$ to be $2$-dimensional.

*Hint 2*

> What happens if $T$ has two distinct eigenvalues in the underlying field?

*Hint 3*

> Can you build an example with $T$ having one eigenvalue with multiplicity two in the underlying field?